# mysql return single result from single table with complex condition

Tags: mysql

I have this table :

table(fied1 int,field2 int,field3 varchar(40));

I would like to obtion without a stored procedure something like:

```
declare int nr default 0;
select coalesce(max(field1),0) into nr from table where field2=? and field3=?;
if(nr = 0) then
  select coalesce(max(field1),0)+1 into nr from table;
end if;
```

i want the value of nr from single select.
pls help !!!

Comment: I think that a case statement should work here, but I'm going to check first before I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use the following query to get one plus to last inserted value in field1 column if no match found as per where clause else it returns the max value stored in field1:

This query is handling the case if there are no records in table.

the filter crieteria "and field1<>0"  in following statement is required if field1 can have value 0 also otherwise remove this filter (and field1<>0) from following query

```
Select coalesce(
   max(field1),
   (select coalesce(max(field1),0)+1 from table)
   ) 
from table where field2=? and field3=? and field1<>0;
```

Comment: is not what i want. If the condition is true i want the value of field1 otherwise i will use "coalesce(max(field1),0)+1"

Comment: if the condition is true field2 = val and field3 = val i need the value of field1 else i want to autoincrement the value of filed1 which can be ....9999. thanks

Comment: The solution doesn't account for cases in which the value of `max(field1)` is actually zero.

Comment: @Romil Right, which is not what OP wants. Look at the if statement in the question.

Comment: still a little help please. I have to do select from multiple tables.

Comment: i have other table : table2(field1 varchar(40)...)mysql> select coalesce(max(t.field1),(select coalesce(max(t.field1),0)+1 from table1 t)) as max,t2.field1 from table2 t2,table1 t where t.field2=1 and field2="val";
+------+-----+
| max  | field1 |
+------+-----+
|    1 | NULL |
+------+-----+
1 row in set (0.21 sec)mysql> select field1 from table2;
+-----+
| field1 |
+-----+
| A   |
| B   |
| N   |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> 
why not return:+------+-----+
| max  | field1 |
+------+-----+
|    1 | A   |
|    1 | B   |
|    1 | N   |
+-----+
????

Comment: please update the post for this issue, so it will be more clear to us.

Answer (score 0):

I think this captures your requirements:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (max(field1) IS NULL OR max(field1) = 0) AND field2=? AND field3=? THEN (max(field1)+1)
    ELSE max(field1)
  END AS `field1_max`
FROM table
```